# Wp8 application custom control which has some dynamic buttons , shows nothing on mainpage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Problem while programmatically generating buttons in a user control of windows phone, and using this user control to mainpage.xaml but there are no buttons shown when application runs.
here is the code snippet which i am using, Thanks !

usercontrol.xaml:

```
 <ScrollViewer >
 <StackPanel x:Name="Panel">
 <ContentControl x:Name="container"></ContentControl>
 </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

usercontrol.xaml.cs:

```
public LoginInterfaceControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.container = new ContentControl();
        this.Panel = new StackPanel();
    }
    public LoginInterfaceControl(string Api_key)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Panel = new StackPanel();
        this.container = new ContentControl();
        loginWP_DownloadString(Api_key);

    }
    public async void loginWP_DownloadString(string key)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string cont;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {   
         var result = await client.GetAsync("http://cdn.loginradius.com/interface/json/" + key + ".json");
            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                cont = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(cont);
            }
            else
            {
                cont = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(cont);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cont))
            { 
            var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(cont);
                int no = 1;
                foreach (var provider in root1.Providers)
                {
                    no++;
                    Button newBtn = new Button()
                    {
                        Content = provider.Name.ToString(),
                        Name = provider.Name.ToString(),
                        //Width = 88,
                        //Height = 77,
                        Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible,
                        //Margin = new Thickness(5 + 20, 5, 5, 5),
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                        VerticalAlignment =VerticalAlignment.Center,
                        Opacity=0.5

                    };
                    newBtn.Click += google_click;
                   System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    container.Opacity = 0.5;
                    this.container.Content = newBtn;   
                } 
            }
        }
```

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid xmlns:src="clr-namespace:LRDemo" 
    Background="White" Margin="10,0,-10,186" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <src:LoginInterfaceControl Grid.Row="0"/>
            <!--<src:LoginInterfaceControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>-->
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you provide full code of your usercontrol?

Comment: Thanks , Updated it with full code of usercontrol !

Comment: Do you want show all the buttons on user control? I mean a loop is there so it will add buttons up to the loop iterates.

Comment: Yes, @DotNetWeblineindia I want to show all dynamic buttons to the **mainpage.xaml** which is my main page of project , so i am using the user control to main page as a local resource therefore i am not getting those dynamic buttons to my mainpage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usercontrol.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ContentControl x:Name="container">
       <StackPanel x:Name="Panel">
       </StackPanel>
   </ContentControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

> > there is no need to again create stackpanel and contentcontrol in constructor of usercontrol because they are already there in usercontrol structure.
> >     Contentcontrol can hold content that is assign to it last so I took stackpanel into contentcontol.

usercontrol.xaml.cs

```
public LoginInterfaceControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    abc();
}

public void abc()
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {

        Button newBtn = new Button()
        {
           Content = "name" + i,
           Name = "name" + i,

           Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
           VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
           Opacity = 0.5

        };

       newBtn.Click += newBtn_Click;

       container.Opacity = 0.5;
       this.Panel.Children.Add(newBtn);
    }
}
```

> > P.S : I do not know your exact need so I took static methods to add buttons.

Comment: Thanks , @DotNetWeblineindia ! 
I tried it , but still not showing those dynamic buttons from a user control to main page !

Comment: I have same code running on my device. So can you tell me what is you latest code after update?

Comment: Thanks !
Worked for me , after asynchronously calling the method !